# powershell wmi cluster resources private properties

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am interesting in using PURE WMI (and not native commandlets) to accomplish this objective.

$test=gwmi -q "Select * from MSCluster_resource" -namespace root\mscluster -computername mycluster -Authentication PacketPrivacy

say i pick a resource based on index

$test[32].privateproperties

All the resources are get;set and I have confirmed this with wbemtest.
But they are part of MSCluster_Property.

How do I SET these via wmi because .privateproperties.put() is not an available method.

I have read this, but not sure how to apply it to powershell.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2010/07/14/10037894.aspx

Once again, not looking for the native commandlets, or using mscluster com.  I have exhausted google.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but what if you just assign new values? Or use the SetPropertyValue method?

```
$test[32].PrivateProperties.SetPropertyValue(string propertyName, System.Object propertyValue)
```